# What is the importance of object oriented programming for competitive programming?

Tags: oop

right now i am learning c++ and oop in c++.I usually practice on Codeforces,but i didn't get any use of object oriented programming for solving any problems.So basically i just want to know that is OOP important for competitive programming??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rarely do we use OOP in competitive programming & Problem solving.
OOP is important when program a system(has many components) to make it more organized.

However,OOP is used(Rarely) in competitive programming to **simplify datatype**..

Here there is an Example..

if you have 1000 point and each of them has its left, right, top ,down value, so to simplify it, we make a class

```
    Class Point
{
int LeftValue;
int RightValue;
int TopValue;
int DownValue;
}
```

Then easily make an array of the "point" class with  the size of 1000

Answer (score 0):

OOP is not really used for competitive programming. Actually vice verca. You would prefer to avoid the overhead of using classes in competitive programming specially that you don't have control over the compiler optimization level. However, to be honest, I do use OOP to simplify the problem, and write the solution faster

Answer (score 0):

Because things in c++ are easy to understand and implement in terms of cp. C++ is the most preferred language for competitive programming mainly because of its STL. Short for Standard Template Library, the STL is a collection of C++ templates to help programmers quickly tackle basic data structures and functions such as lists, stacks, arrays, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a C++ programmer and same question arises in my mind also .But the think is you can use oops concept in CP **If the question asked you to manage you data **like if question ask to make a program where the data is your crushial think so you can use data encapsulation..
But in case of memory management you should go through for procedural programming